# How do TypeScript mixins work (in Angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript, mixins

Currently I'm using mixins in Angular to extend my component's functions. All my mixins look like this:

```
export function mixinTest<T extends AbstractConstructor<ComponentBase>>(Base: T) {
    abstract class MixinTest extends Base {
        //Logic here
    };

    return MixinTest;
}

export function mixinTest2<T extends AbstractConstructor<ModelComponentBase<unknown>>>(Base: T) {
    abstract class MixinTest2 extends Base {
        //Logic here
    };

    return MixinTest2;
}
```

Where `ComponentBase` is a base component of which I have several. I'm using a mix of inheritance and mixins. Inheritance, where it makes sense (to not lose Angulars annotations (@Input, @Output etc.) and mixin functions for *special* logic.

Now I have a `ModelComponentBase<T>` too, that has a property `model: T`. If I now add a mixin that extends `ComponentBase` I lose the model property: the compiler tells me `Property 'model' does not exist on type 'TestComponent'.`:

```
export class TestComponent extends mixinTest(mixinTest2(ModelComponentBase))<Task> {
    method(): void {
        this.model$.subscribe(t => this.task = <Task>t);
    }
    task: Task;
}
```

But it works, if I take care of the order:

```
export class TestComponent extends mixinTest2(mixinTest(ModelComponentBase))<Task> {
    method(): void {
        this.model$.subscribe(t => this.task = <Task>t);
    }
    task: Task;
}
```

**or** use only one mixin:

```
export class TestComponent extends mixinTest(ModelComponentBase)<Task> {
    method(): void {
        this.model$.subscribe(t => this.task = <Task>t);
    }
    task: Task;
}
```

**and** it even **works**, if I mixin the functions in multiple steps:

```
const ctor = mixinTest2(ModelComponentBase);
const ctor2 = mixinTest(ctor);
export class TestComponent extends ctor2<Task> {
    method(): void {
        this.model$.subscribe(t => this.task = <Task>t);
    }
    task: Task;
}
```

Why does this make a difference? I thought it shouldn't matter? By the way: `AbstractContructor` is taken from Angular Material: `export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;`

So my questions are:

1. Do I use mixins correct at all? Or is my `mixinTest` already malformed?
2. Why does the order care? Why does the amount of mixins make a difference?
3. Using mixins with `ModelComponentBase<unknown>` makes the model become type `unknown | T`. Is there a way to use generic parameters with my `mixinTest2`?